# Create files in subdirectories with the same name

Tags: python, linux, perl, awk

Reading a list with A and B data in 2 columns, iterating row by row, I was createding a series of direcoties with the following logic.
read first row, data A and B, create folder A and subfolder B ( mkdir -p A/B ) and so on.
Well, now, I need to create a corresponding file B.txt ( i.e ) inside the proper subfolder B.

By example, y made some proofs with a single file with the next content.

```
col1  col2
  a     b
  c     d
```

I created the foler sructure with the next line:

```
    awk 'NR>1{system("mkdir -p "$1"/"$2)} my_file.txt
```

The result was:

```
$ tree
a
 |_b
c
 |_d
```

Now I would like to invoke that directory path, to move or create for example a file named b.txt to the directory with the same name, and so be able to do it with the whole tree, but I could not do it yet

My spected result.

```
$ tree
a
 |_b
   |_b.txt
c
 |_d
   |_d.txt
```

Any idia?

Thanks

Comment: What code you have created so far? What's the issue you are having?

Comment: Hi mdem7, thank you for your answer. My code use awk to read a txt file, and create the folders. awk'NR>1{system("mkdir -p "$1"/"2)}' my_file.txt. But I find some problems to create o move a specific file named like B subfolder to that folder.

Comment: Hi zero, welcome to StackOverflow. When you post, you should share a minimal example of the code you have written, as well as the input and output you expect to get from the code, as well as the output you actually get. See the guidelines for posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment d_kennetz

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52537707

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will be closed on the StackOverflow, but it would be likely ontopic on the https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps better to do in `bash` directly since there is nothing requires `awk`

```
$ while read -r a b; 
  do mkdir -p "$a/$b"; touch "$a/$b/$b.txt"; 
  done < <(sed 1d file)


$ tree
.
├── a
│   └── b
│       └── b.txt
├── c
│   └── d
│       └── d.txt
└── file

4 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your hel Karafca